# Undefined is not a function react apollo compose react native

Tags: react-native, react-apollo

I am trying to create a sample app using React Native to get real-time data from AWS Appsync and GraphqlAPI. I am getting below error when I am trying to compose multiple components using compose. Please help

[image]

Below is my code

```
const AppWithData = compose(
          graphqlMutation(createTodo, listTodos, 'Todo'),
          graphql(listTodos, {
            options: {
              fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
            },
            props: ({ data }) => ({
              todos: data.listTodos ? data.listTodos.items : [],
              data
            })
          })
        )(App)`
    
    export default withAuthenticator(AppWithData, { includeGreetings: true })
```